# Parse csv along comparing txt file lined and log lines not found

Tags: powershell

As a continuation of a script I'm running, working on the following.

I have a CSV file that has formatted information, example as follows:

File named Import.csv:

```
Name,email,x,y,z
\I\RS\T\Name1\c\x,email@jksjks,d,f
\I\RS\T\Name2\d\f,email@jsshjs,d,f
...
```

This file is large.

I also have another file called Note.txt.

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
...
```

With help from @mathias-r-jessen

```
$Dir = PathToFile
$import = Import-Csv $Dir\import.csv
$NoteFile = "$Dir\Note.txt"
$Note = GC $NoteFile

$Import |Where-Object {$Note -contains $_.Name.Split('\')[4]} |Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

This code quickly and effortlessly parses the big csv and extracts every line that contains any of the lines in the $note file.

My next question is how do i log any lines in the $note file that were not found in the csv file.

I tried the following:

```
$result = $Import |Where-Object {$Note -contains $_.Name.Split('\')[4]} |Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

$Note | Where-Object {$result.Name.Split('\')[4] -notcontains $Note} | out-file $dir\not-found.log -append
```

This seems to return every line in $note.

@mathias-r-jessen any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The $unmatchedrows variable is not doing anything.  I added the exports to the matched rows, how do I get the $unmatchedrows, I tried adding an out-file but it just says: split

Comment: `$note | where-object { -not ($Import.Name -match $_)}` ? ( I misread that you wanted CSV rows not in the notes )

Comment: @tessellatingHeckler What I want is the line (for example Name2) of the Notes file, that did not match anything in the csv file, and I want to log the Name2 in a log file.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen any thoughts on this?

Comment: Was anything wrong with `$note | where-object { -not ($Import.Name -match $_)}` ? It looks a lot simpler than Compare-Object

Comment: @tessellatingHeckler  For some reason it was skipping the first Name in the Note file, then listing all the others.  Not exactly the output required.  It was supposed to add to the log file the ones that weren't in the csv but wasn't doing it, not sure why, the logic was there.  I appreciate the help though, without it wouldn't have gotten as far.  Im learning though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the following:

```
$result = $Import |Where-Object {$Note -contains $_.Name.Split('\')[4]} 

$result | Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

$matches =  $note | where-object { $result.Name -match $_}

compare-object $note $matches |where-object {$_.SideIndicator -like "<=" | select -ExpandProperty InputObject | Out-file "$Dir\Not_found.txt" -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Switch` to do that.

```
Switch($Import){
    {$Note -contains $_.Name.Split('\')[4]} {$_ | Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append; continue}
    default {$_ | Export-csv "$Dir\Not-Found.csv" -NoType -Append}
}
```

The `continue` in the first option makes it so that if the first case is a match it performs the relevant action, and then continues to the next record. If the first case doesn't match it moves on to the default action, which outputs it to a different file.